# Extract tables from SSAS TABULAR in Databricks

Tags: python, azure, scala, apache-spark, databricks

We are working on a solution where we have data in SSAS Tabular solution and that need to be imported into Databricks for further transpose. Currently we are connecting to excel export the data and load it manually into data bricks.

We want to automate this process to avoid manual effort. We are looking for any scala or python connector available which could extract data from SSAS and load into databricks dataframe.

Any help or suggestion is welcome.